# Obscured div within script how to assign click on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have a script which is obscured (ie cannot read the div elements from script). Upon rendering in inspect DOM element I can locate what the div I want to assign a function to. However I cannot do this. Do I need the div id within the script (ie obscured div id)?

I want to assign click on function and plan do it as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('.contentoverlay').on('mouseover', function() {
     click();
   });

});
</script>
```

The script in itself is very long so I won't paste it here.

Overall I want to know:

1. Do I need to locate the obscure script's div is and assign my click function to it
2. Is the function above correct
3. If there are multiple overlays do I have to assign the function above to each one (the overlays in themselves are mouse pointer none, so they do pass down clicks, but would the function above get passed down or even blocked if I don't assign it to all the overlays)?

Comment: did you mean like this? http://jsbin.com/joxetuc

Comment: Not like this. For example if script file reads something like: <div id="jkjkh".....> and then the dom output reads <div id=example..... What I want to know if when assigning on mouseover execute click do I need to assign it to what the script is (ie div id="jkjkh") as I have tried assigning it to <div id=example.. and nothing happens

Comment: answer my question: 1. the element is already in there OR it new created from ajax/js script? 2. did you know the different between on('click') vs click() ? (sry for my bad english), btw, try to see my jsbin again that i was updated for you

Comment: @plonknimbuzz thanks for the reply. 1) The element is newly created by the script. When I look inspect in DOM and cross-reference the div id I cannot see this id/name in the script so I know the script uses obsecurification techniques. I want to understand how do I implement click if mouse is hovered. 2) on('click') is when a function is executed after a click and click() is to execute click function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example: http://output.jsbin.com/joxetuc

First, i want explain my comment first, then i will answer your 3 questions in the end

A) honestly i have bad english here, i dont know what "obscured" means (even i google this), but i think that's means new DOM that newly created (dynamic created element) by javascript. like this:
started DOM `<table></table>`

New DOM `<tr><td>texttt</td></tr>`

the result `<table><tr><td>texttt</td></tr></table>`

> **if this not correct, my whole answer below will be wrong.**

B) So, in jsbin example, i only give you div#container. And then create new DOM inside div#container when you click **created** button.

C) i create 1 function to handle if new DOM is clicked, which will write $(element).text() to div.log

```
//function to execute if element clicked
       $('.container').on('click', '#newid', function(i,e){
         var txt = $(this).text();
         $('.log').append(txt+' ');
       });
```

D) i handling event mouseover too with same function in click function. Because i'm lazy, i only write `$(this).click();` which `$(this)` is refer to div#newid

```
//if mouseover, perform click
       $('.container').on('mouseover', '#newid', function(i,e){
         $(this).click();
       });
```

so, in that jsbin i show you how to handle mouseover new DOM to execute click() function.

## Now, Your Question

*1) Do I need to locate the obscure script's div is and assign my click function to it?*

You dont need it, as long as you know how to locate that element.

*2) Is the function above correct?*

that's not correct function. the correct 1 is:

```
parentElemenentOfNewDOM.on('mouseover', newDOMElement, function() {
$(this).click(); //this will perform your default click function that you give before
});
```

*3) If there are multiple overlays do I have to assign the function above to each one (the overlays in themselves are mouse pointer none, so they do pass down clicks, but would the function above get passed down or even blocked if I don't assign it to all the overlays)?*

you dont need to assign same function to handle multiple element (overlays). What you need is the correct script to handle all of your new multiple element. And my script will handle all of the new element.

if you want to know the different, see this DEMO http://output.jsbin.com/vukudu

Comment: thanks a lot. Obscure means trying to hide it by coding. In my case the script is coded such that the raw coding is translated differently when rendered. So basically i can't see the element id by looking at the code and I can only find it when it is rendered in DOM. What I want to know is can I execute a function on the rendered DOM id or do I need the raw obscure id to execute. 2) thank's for the correct function I have seen you jsbin and will use this. 3) As there is too many obscure elements can I just select the one element and pass this click/hover down to all elements?